# Update span text from input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input tag and I want to take its value and put it in a span after a simple calculation. I did it but the value update only when the user hit the "Enter" button. Is there any way to do it dynamicaly? Without pushing the button.

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6">
   Number:<input id="number" type="int" onchange="updateInput(this.value)">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6">
   Total <span id="result"></span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function updateInput(ish){
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = ish*0.05
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

j08691's answer will work, but it won't include all ways that the user can update the value (such as pasting it).  This should cover everything:

```
$("#number").bind("propertychange change keyup paste input", function () {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = $("#number").val()*0.05;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to change:

```
onchange="updateInput(this.value)"
```

to

```
onkeyup="updateInput(this.value)"
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6x2As/)**